# What is the correct mustache template config for _.templateSettings of underscore.template?

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js, mustache

I've searched around and I couldn't find one that really works.

In Mustache, when you throw 2 curly, the string inside will be escaped, and if you throw 3, it will NOT.

```
// when you pass {foo: '"bar"'} as hash, the following template will be: 
 {{foo}}  // => &quot;bar&quot;
{{{foo}}} // => "bar"
```

right? So I created the following.

http://jsfiddle.net/beatak/6s5PU/

and this shows interpolate and escape opposite, meaning 2 curly for unescaped 3 for escaped. When I flip between `escape` and `interpolate` in `_.templateSettings`, it just doesn't work.  WHY? Underscore template has precedence of those three (`escape`, `interpolate` and `evaluate`)?

I know I'm ignoring `evaluate` on jsfiddle now, if that works together that'll be fantastic, but for now, I want to make 2 and 3 curly works just fine…

Comment: You get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in `underscore.js:1151`. Probably a bug; a JavaScript string is concatenated and tried to be evaluated. ([at this section](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-133))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex for escape is searched, then interpolate, then evaluate. That's why your escaped form `{{ }}` is matching before your unescaped form `{{{ }}}`. You can change the order yourself in the source for `_.template`.

```
var matcher = new RegExp([
  (settings.escape || noMatch).source,
  (settings.interpolate || noMatch).source,
  (settings.evaluate || noMatch).source
].join('|') + '|$', 'g');
```

Changing the order of the lines above will change the priority.

If you don't want to change the underscore priority, you can use a more complex escaping regular expression. It's tricky to do without negative look-behind, but I came up with:

```
/\{\{([^\{\}]+?)(?!\}\}\})\}\}/
```

which should mean: `{{`, followed by one or more *non-brace* characters, that shall not be followed by triple brace (`}}}`), followed by double brace `}}`. It works on your fiddle and hopefully will work for you.

Comment: THAT SEEMS WORKING. AWESOME!